# Dynamically handle requests with a webpage

Tags: javascript, request, html

I would like to do the following: send a GET request for an URL, which is a normal webpage, that continuously listens for GET requests, and when one occurs, makes an event (some kind of javascript event, like display something in the webpage for a short time), then it listens for the next incoming requests.

Do you have any ideas how should I do this? I was thinking about AJAX, that maybe it can solve my problem, but not sure about that, also I don't know much about AJAX, but if it's the solution for my problem, then I'm gonna learn how to use it. Or if not AJAX, is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a page to listen for events then you could use something like [websockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

Otherwise you would need that page to poll a url using AJAX.